# Using Assumptions with Sign

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to use Mathematica to quickly determine the sign of a derivative. When I use the function Sign, Mathematica informs me the answer depends on the sign of a numerator, which is rather long. Following some advice on using $Assumptions, I have now tried the following, but without the desired effect; I would have thought that Mathematica would have replaced Sign[ ] with -1 or 1 when it has been input the restrictions:

```
$Assumptions = 0 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 && c == 1 

Sign[(b c (-I \[Pi] + Log[-b + (-1 + b) a] - Log[-b + (1 + b) a]) + c (-4 Log[a] + I (-2 + b) (\[Pi] + I Log[-b + (-1 + b) a]) + (2 + b) Log[-b + (1 + b) a]) a)/(b^2 (-1 + a)^3)]
```

Comment: Is my code correct?

Comment: The `Sign[0]` is `0`, `Sign[Indeterminate]` is `Indeterminate`, and `Sign[z]` is `z/Abs[z]` if `z` is a nonzero complex number.  That last two can occur in the specified domain.

Comment: Also, generally you have to apply a function that makes use of `$Assumptions` (such as `Simplify`) in order for the assumptions to have an effect.  I don't think `Sign` uses `$Assumptions`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$Assumptions=...` to define global attributes of variables!